# Azure B2C - security questions

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a client using B2C on a small scale looking to scale up to support 100,000 users.

Questions are as follows:

1 The documentation suggests lockout after 10 failed login attempts. Is it on the roadmap to allow users to configure lockout policies? (The client sees this as a security weakness)
2 To change the UPN for a user do we still need to use Graph API?
3 B2C user feedback messages to end users does not meet internal stakeholder expectations (they don’t like the error messages as they give information about if a username is valid or not) the customer seeks to customise this and understand how to customize look and feel in line with internal guidelines (The client sees this as a security weakness)

Thanks!

Comment: Stuart, is the client using Built-in user flow or Custom Policies? There is a lot more possible in custom policies.The answers to your some of questions depends on that parameter.

Comment: Thanks Abhidhek - much appreciated. Yes they are happy to use custom policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, I recommend making three separate posts for the three questions. Helps to make each question more searchable - and also follows the Stack Overflow guidelines. In the meantime:

1. Smart lockout is on the roadmap, but you should vote for the feature here to help the team prioritize - https://aka.ms/aadb2cfeedback
2. You cannot change the UPN, but why would you want to?
3. You can customize all strings in Azure AD B2C - see here for built-in policies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-language-customization